# Whatsapp web qrcode flashes and dissapears

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp

I'm running chrome on ubuntu 16.04
[Whatsapp web](https://web.whatsapp.com/) seems to have stopped working on the desktop. 
The QR code flashes on the screen for what looks like 1 frame before disappearing to leave only the whatsapp logo.

In search, I have found answers suggesting socks proxy settings. When I go to *settings->network->Network Proxy*, the Method is set to *None*.

I also tired deleting all the PC sessions on my android device.

I have also tried killing all the chrome processes.

I have not tried rebooting yet.

Comment: I checked whatsapp web on Ubuntu 16.04, on both firefox and chrome, and didn't notice any issue. What happened after reboot when you try using firefox? chrome?

Comment: Do you have a firewall enabled that may be blocking the image from loading? Does it work with other browsers? Have you tried clearing your browser's cookies and cache?

Comment: Please report this bug (possibly related to hardware acceleration, possibly not) to the WhatsApp developers. They cannot fix it if they don't know about it.

Comment: Bug is reported. Still not clear if this is ubuntu specific...dont have another platform to test on.

Comment: @SpiRail on Arch the same problem

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was having the same problem and was able to fix it by going into *Settings → Advanced* and disabling hardware acceleration.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! Although it would be good to have hardware acceleration at times.

Comment: Actaully, one can just click "remember me"on the whatsapp page, then put acceleration back on and restart the browser and it works fine after.

Comment: Wow, this works. It was strange to see that is was working on some of my Computers and not all the time.

Comment: It was also causing me images turning black when uploading them on WhatsApp Web and problems on PDF preview of Overleaf. Disabling hardware acceleration fixed it all.